# Pass multiple variables between pages to the html url from flask

Tags: python, flask

I need to pass two variables in the url from one html page to another. It turned out to pass one "name" and it looks like: http://localhost/push_web?service_name=test

But I need to pass it so that it turns out something like: http://localhost/push?name=test&token=21hgsgwqyqy8218gddsyqwaw22

But this does not work, only the name variable is passed to the url, and the token is written to the cell as None. What am I doing wrong? Or is it impossible to do this in HTML?

My code what have I tried:

flask:

```
session['name'] = name
session['token'] = token           
return redirect(url_for('push_web'))
```

```
@app.route('/push')
def push():
    name = request.args.get('name', None)
    token = request.args.get('token', None)
    return render_template("push.html", name=request.args.get('name', None), token=request.args.get('token', None))
```

in html:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('push', name=name, token=token ) }}">Page</a>
```

I was expecting a page like: http://localhost/push?name=test&token=21hgsgwqyqy8218gddsyqwaw22

But I only succeeded: http://localhost/push?name=test

Comment: You are fetching `name` and `token` from the URL.  Did you mean to fetch them from the session?

Comment: Yes, I would like to understand why it is not possible to take the second variable token=request.args.get('token', None) from the session Maybe HTML needs to be written in a different way somehow? I write <a href="{{ url_for('push', name=name, token=token ) }}">Page</a>

Comment: You CAN take them from the session, but that's not what you're doing.  You should be doing `name = session['name']`, not getting them from the request.

Comment: Please read more, I tried what you wrote, but it didn't work anywhere.

Comment: I figured out everything myself, it worked as it should in this version (html remained the same): `@app.route('/push')
def push():
    name = request.args.get('name', None)
    token = request.args.get('token', None)
    return render_template("push.html", name=name, token=token)` Plus, I inserted the code in the wrong place in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, in my case it worked like this:

Flask(Python):
I take the variables from here:

```
   session['name'] = name
   session['token'] = token           
   return redirect(url_for('push'))
```

I put variables here here:

```
@app.route('/push') 
   def push():     
       name = request.args.get('name', None)     
       token = request.args.get('token', None)     
       return render_template("push.html", name=name, token=token)
```

HTML:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('push', name=name, token=token ) }}">Page</a>
```

Result: `http://localhost/push?name=test&token=21hgsgwqyqy8218gddsyqwaw22`

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is intended to work:

```
@app.route('/push')
def push():
    name = session.get('name', None)
    token = session.get('token', None)
    return render_template("push.html", name=name, token=token)
```

Comment: It worked only in this version: `@app.route('/push') def push():     name = request.args.get('name', None)     token = request.args.get('token', None)     return render_template("push.html", name=name, token=token)`
For some reason, your version gives: `None`